# Python MySQLdb - Getting a ValueError

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Trying to import a list into MySQL through Python with MySQLdb...code below.

I get a ValueError when I run it -

```
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 51
```

Code_

```
import MySQLdb
import ystockquote
import re

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
       user= '****',
       passwd='****',
       db='****')
cur = mydb.cursor()

name = raw_input('please input a symbol_')
data = ystockquote.get_all(name)
stock = data.values()
clean = (", ".join(stock))
#var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(clean))
query_string = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO YAHOO VALUES (\"%s\");' % clean
cur.execute(query_string, clean)
print clean
```

When I print query_string the statement looks good and the 'clean' values appear to be in good shape - any help would be kindly appreciated.

```
print clean
1.52, -59.49%, 0.93, 0.17, 800, "1.51 - 1.59", 1.54, 1.59, N/A, -0.01, +5.25%, 0.16, N/A, 0.08, -2.32, N/A, 6.90M, -1.24, N/A, N/A, 1.50, 100, 326754, N/A, N/A, N/A, N/A, 1.51, "NYQ", N/A, "0.93 - 3.90", N/A, "3:48pm - <b>1.58</b>", "Ciber, "+3.95%", N/A, 3700, N/A, N/A, -34.46%, N/A, 2.84, N/A, N/A, N/A, 0.65, N/A, 127.47M, N/A, +69.89%, 2.63, N/A, N/A, 693036, 1.58, -0.65, 73289000, N/A, N/A, -0.83, 0.53, 80680000, N/A, N/A, N/A,  Inc. Common Stock", 3.90, "6/14/2016", -0.16, N/A, N/A, 760.00M, +0.06, N/A, N/A, N/A, 2.41, "3:48pm", N/A, "+0.06 - +3.95%", 326754

print query_string
INSERT IGNORE INTO YAHOO VALUES ("1.52, -59.49%, 0.93, 0.17, 800, "1.51 - 1.59", 1.54, 1.59, N/A, -0.01, +5.25%, 0.16, N/A, 0.08, -2.32, N/A, 6.90M, -1.24, N/A, N/A, 1.50, 100, 335969, N/A, N/A, N/A, N/A, 1.51, "NYQ", N/A, "0.93 - 3.90", N/A, "3:51pm - <b>1.58</b>", "Ciber, "+3.95%", N/A, 3700, N/A, N/A, -34.46%, N/A, 2.84, N/A, N/A, N/A, 0.65, N/A, 127.47M, N/A, +69.89%, 2.63, N/A, N/A, 693036, 1.58, -0.65, 73289000, N/A, N/A, -0.83, 0.53, 80680000, N/A, N/A, N/A,  Inc. Common Stock", 3.90, "6/14/2016", -0.16, N/A, N/A, 760.00M, +0.06, N/A, N/A, N/A, 2.41, "3:51pm", N/A, "+0.06 - +3.95%", 335969");
```

Comment: please show us content of `query_string` and `clean`

Comment: does table `YAHOO` only have 1 column?

Comment: no, 81, named to match each data point in the 'stock' return.

Comment: is 59% legal value?  should it be quoted?

Answer (score 1):

[`.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) expect 2 arguments when using with wildcards or string replacement in the following manner:

- query_string with value placeholders `%s`
- a tuple of values that will replace the above `%s`

you don't need to manually "clean" your values. I also included the column names in the query to make it clear:

```
data = ystockquote.get_all(name)
stock = data.values()
columns = data.keys()
columns[columns.index('change')] = '_change'
var_string = '%s' + ',%s' * (len(stock)-1))
query_string = '''
    INSERT IGNORE INTO YAHOO 
    ('''+','.join('`%s`' % (c,) for c in columns)+''') 
    VALUES (%s);''' % var_string
cur.execute(query_string, tuple(stock))
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit how the var_string is cleaning up the 'stock' returns - greatly appreciated!

Comment: error - 
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 73

Comment: @citramaillo, weird. did you get this error from my latest answer?

Comment: @citramaillo, sorry. my `var_string` was constructed incorrectly. see updated answer

Comment: another, similar error -
 query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 1387

Comment: result of print query_string....

INSERT IGNORE INTO YAHOO 
    (previous_close,shares_owned,change_from_52_week_low,revenue,average_daily_volume,todays_range_realtime, etc.......) 
    VALUES (%s,%,%,%, etc..............

Comment: @citramaillo, you are probably missing an `s` after `%` in `var_string = '%s' + ',%s' * (len(stock)-1))`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ystock.py", line 20, in <module>
    cur.execute(query_string, tuple(stock))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change,eps_estimate_next_yea

Comment: @citramaillo, looks like `change` is a mysql reserved word, so we need to escape it with the tick symbol. see updated answer

Comment: similar but now explicit call to 'change' - self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'change' in 'field list'")

Comment: I escaped it in MySQL as _change

Comment: @citramaillo, do you mean your column name is `_change` instead of `change`?

Comment: yes - when I created the tabled I edited the name in MySQL

thanks for your patience!

Comment: @citramaillo. got it. I added a line to substitute `change` with `_change`.